# How to make a template content non editable in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I've crated html template file, I put some elements inside that template are non editable.

template.html contains

```
<body>
<div>This is a sample template </div>
<div contenteditable="false" style="color:red">Read Only Text</div>
</body>
```

on inserting this template file into the textarea the second div is editable, while inspecting over that div I've seen that the attribute **contenteditable="false"** is not there on insert, but its there on the preview before the insert of template.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: did you try not putting contenteditable on the second div?

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu yes i've tried that and also tinymce plugin noneditable
second div content has red color but that attribute is not in there on insert

Comment: you mentioned about the noneditable plugin, so I assume that you have already visited this page: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/noneditable_content.php and I assume that you have followed the instructions carefully. The example in the page seems to be working fine, are you sure you've followed the instructions on how to use the plugin carefully?

Comment: I've tried that plugin but there is some other problems, I've a select box called addheader on select it is inserted non editable content in to the textarea. if i use the plugin and select addheader the whole line becomes noneditable

Answer (score 2):

From this page: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/noneditable_content.php

Its using a textarea:

```
  <textarea name="content" style="width:100%">
    &lt;p&gt;Text with a &lt;span class="mceNonEditable"&gt;[non editable]&lt;/span&gt; inline element.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p class="mceNonEditable"&gt;Noneditable text block with &lt;span class="mceEditable"&gt;[editable]&lt;/span&gt; items within.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Text with tokens that isn't [[editable]] since they match the noneditabe_regexp.&lt;/p&gt;
  </textarea>
```

The key here is putting a class of mceNonEditable in your element:

```
span class="mceNonEditable"
```

Then whatever non-editable content you have, wrap it in greater than and less than:

```
&gt;You cannot edit me&lt;
```

Then finally close the element:

```
/span
```

I think you can also change the mode (in the example they're using textareas, so I guess you can also use divs or spans) when initializing tinymce:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        noneditable_regexp: /\[\[[^\]]+\]\]/g
});
```

There's also noneditable_regexp which lets you specify a regular expression of non-editable contents.
I think this is easier than using html entities.

I haven't actually tried it but that's the way I interpret the example in the page.

Comment: If i use this regex `/(<(div|DIV)\s+class\s*?=('|")\s*?replace('|")\s*?>)(\s*?&lt;)(.*?)(&gt;\s*?)(<\/(div|DIV)\s*?>)/g` then the div contains class replace should be noneditable right, but it is not possible to use regex over the html content